# Ускорить выборку в селекционированных таблицах Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, partition

Хочу увеличить скорость выборки в селекционированых таблицах. Заранее напишу, что я использую селекцию - `partition by list`.

В чем собственно проблема и почему нужна фича для ускорения выборки данных из селекционных (partition) таблицах.

У меня есть таблица (обычная), в которой находятся объекты и эти самые объекты могут находятся в разных партицированных таблицах, НО данные по объектам, которые мне нужны могут быть в разных партициях (в каких я не знаю) и мне приходится 'перелапачивать' все партицированные таблицы для поиска нужных мне.

У меня такой вопрос как можно работать с селекцией, чтобы обращаться только к нужным мне данным и тем самым ускорить запрос, а может есть некоторые фичи для работы... Любой инф буду рад.

Comment: А по какому именно выражению таблица секционирована? PS. Именно секционирована, а не се**ле**кционирована.

Comment: @Akina Ой и правда секционирование... Задумался и написал не то о чем думал... Секционирование делалось по комбинации (страна, город, тип, год) Исп partition by list –

Comment: Что то не ясное в формулировке "_мне приходится 'перелапачивать' все партицированные таблицы для поиска нужных мне_". Вы это делаете самостоятельно ? Или как это у вас происходит. Оптимизатор должен сам разобраться какие секции задействовать, в случае если выражение в запросе подходящее (а если не подходящее то вопрос к проектированию и почему ключ секционирования отличается от используемого в запросах)